# illegal start of expression if statements

Tags: java, jcreator

I'm not sure where the error in the if statement is, any help is appreciated.

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Exercise4P94 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int carNum;
    boolean chck;
    do {
        chck = true;
        System.out.println("Enter the Car Model Number: ");
        carNum = input.nextInt();

        if (carNum == 119 || carNum == 179 || carNum >== 189 && carNum <== 195 || carNum == 221 || carNum == 780){
            System.out.println("Your car is defective and must be repaired");
        } else if (!(carNum == 119 || carNum == 179 || carNum >= 189 && carNum <= 195 || carNum == 221 || carNum == 780)){
            System.out.println("Your car is not defective");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid car model number");
            chck = false;
        }
    } while (chck);
}
```

}

Comment: `>==` and `<==` are wrong. It should be `>=` and `<=`.

Comment: look at `carNum >== 189 && carNum <== 195` and tell me if there is anything wrong w/that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need two equal signs after a greater/less than sign

```
 carNum >= 189 && carNum <= 195
```

Comment: Damn. It's hard to see when reading over yourself. Thanks man.

Comment: @EpicNicks That's why you should use an IDE that will highlight such problems for you.

Comment: Which would you recommend? I looked into Eclipse, and JCreator is just for school.

Comment: @EpicNicks Eclipse is good, also check out IntelliJ (not free)